# speciality of the binary sequence $\underline{100101100110100}101101001$

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

One friend has given me this binary sequence and asked what is its speciality if we add next few terms to this sequence?
The binary sequence was:
$$\color{blue}{\underline{100101100110100}}101101001 \dots$$
Hints Given: It's a Classical one.
So,could anyone please help me to recognise its speciality...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is it:

> The (opposite of the) [Thue-Morse sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence).
>
>  Start with $1 \to 10 \to 1001 \to 10010110 \to 1001011001101001$, where at each step the opposite of what is already there is added.

Comment: Note for the curious: this is in fact equivalent to gopal's answer.

Answer (score 2):

It could be

> Binary strings that have 1s where 'evil numbers' occur, 0s elsewhere and every term ends >!with the n-th evil number index (counting with 0 = first).

Source-OEIS

Comment: Note for the curious: this is in fact equivalent to JonMark Perry's answer.

Answer (score -1):

It could be:

> Morse code with a 1 as a dot, a 11 as a dash, 0 as a gap between dots and dashes, and 00 as gap between letters.

In which case:

> The message becomes "EANRE". Not sure if this is if any note...

Comment: Curiously, Morse is relevant here, but not _that_ Morse.